# Convexity proof involving integral

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

[image]

> In the very first paragraph, it is written to observe that because the Poisson kernel is positive and has the unit integral (these two facts I have already proved), the point $f(z)$ is a weighted $\cdots \cdots$ so $ f(z)$ must lie in $\Omega$ for every $z\in D.$ Why the argument is true, I am not aware? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by definition [the weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function) of $f$ is
$$\dfrac{\int_D f(x)w(x)dx}{\int_D w(x)dx}$$
where $\phi(z)=f(z)$ and weighted function is the Poisson kernel, and we know $P(e^{i\theta},z)=\dfrac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}$ such that 
$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}P(e^{i\theta},z)d\theta=1$$
so with $w=P(e^{i\theta},z)$ statement s clear.

Comment: But why the integral will be there in $\Omega$ as written in the book? Is it because the weighted average will be there in $\Omega$?

Comment: Because weighted function fill out the whole of interior of $\Gamma$, which is mainly the **convex hull** of it, here assumed to be convex in supposition.